# Using eval() not work in IE8 and IE 7 but works in IE9, FF,Chrome?

Tags: javascript, eval

I have problem regarding eval(), i'm validating the data that the user submit using a object javascript..

E.g.

```
for(var i=0;i<count;i++){

     switch(caseType){
       case: 'Group':
        ### it will execute the ff code
        ### it will call MustChecked function

        if(!eval(this.MustChecked(getAttribute('class'), getAttribute('min'), getAttribute('max')))) {

           ####this will alert all the errors..
          this.AddError(i, getAttribute("msg"));
        }
     }


}
```

From this code, it will alert all errors... This code is not Working in IE8 and IE7... Anyone have an idea why is not working in  IE8 and IE7?

**UPDATED: MUSTCHECKED FUNCTION**

> ```
> MustChecked : function(name, min, max)
>   {
>       var groups = document.getElementsByClassName(name);
>       alert(groups);
>       //console.log(name + ":" + groups.length);
>       var hasChecked = 0;
>       min = min || 1;
>       max = max || groups.length;
>       for(var i=groups.length-1;i>=0;i--)
>           if(groups[i].checked) hasChecked++;
>           return min <= hasChecked && hasChecked <= max;
>   },
> ```

**UPDATE V1.1**

I tried like this

```
getElementsByClassName : function (className) {
        if (document.getElementsByClassName) { 
          return document.getElementsByClassName(className); 
        }
        else { 
            return document.querySelectorAll('.' + className); 
        } 
},
```

This work in IE8 but not in IE7... any luck?

Comment: What does `this.MustChecked` return?

Comment: It return true or false... It check if the there are checkbox that are checked or not

Comment: if it returns true or false, there no reason to use eval in if

Comment: if this.MustChecked returns a boolean all you have to do is: `if(!this.MustChecked(...)){}`

Comment: Can't really help much without knowing what is actually being eval'ed. Try adding a `console.log()` of the `MustChecked()` function output ahead of the eval, to see what is actually being run. But in general, my advice is to avoid `eval()` whenever possible - virtually any time you see an `eval()`, there is almost always a better way of doing things.

Comment: @sdepold i did that already but still doesn't work in IE8 and IE7 but other browsers are ok..

Comment: The answer to this problem almost certainly lies in the `MustChecked` function. Please provide the code for that function.

Comment: i updated already.. my post.. please do check the mustChecked function...

Answer (score 3):

The `getElementsByClassName` method is not supported in IE7/8. And you use it in your `MustChecked` function.

Not supported as in "doesn't exist".

There are shims available. Quickly googling will give your some results. Or you could use Sizzle or simply a `querySelectorAll` shim, which are much more generic.

If you want to find out if a feature is supported, a good resource is [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=getElementsByClassName).

Comment: Your right my friend, GetElementByClassName doesn't work in IE7 and IE8.. i tried like this..

Comment: @AnthonyPillos querySelectorAll exists in IE8, not in IE7. You need to include a shim if you want it to work in IE7.